# read some website content python

Tags: python, html, web, urllib

I want to get from this page - http://www.info.com/searchqcat=web&r_cop=search&cmp=3294&cb=13&qkw=google

one or more from the **ads** , as shown in the picture :

[image]

Comment: Share your code so that we can help you.

Comment: I dont have one :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's built-in module [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). You could also use Beautiful Soup.

#### html.parser

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

#### Beautiful Soup

- [http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ezlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html)
- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/